# UINavigationBar should be opaque but a transparent PNG image should allow background to be visible

Tags: ios, transparency, uinavigationbar

My Output is as such:
As you can see, the gray pixel background in the content area starts after the cutty edges of my navigationbar.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUqqX.png

But my requirement is as follows:

I want the navigation bar to be opaque.
But should there be any transparent section in the navigation bar image, then  the bottom gray pixel background image should be visible.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHjVg.jpg

What I assume as the solution would be if the background image can be scaled all the way to the top behind the navigationBar section. In that case, if there is a transparency in the navigationBar image, the pixel background would be visible.

Please suggest if anyone has the idea to achieve this.

Comment: Set the background color of your UINavigationBar to clearColor?

Comment: Even if I do that, there is no gray pixel background that goes behind the UINavigationBar
I want the gray pixel background to go all the way up, even behind the UINavigationBar, which I don't know how to achieve.

Comment: You have to extend the frame of your view to go under the navbar. Normally it stops at the edge.

Comment: Thanks @ryan-poolos, knew I have to do that but wasn't able to figure out how.

The answer is to set the bounds of the view such that it moves a little under the UINavigationBar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is facing a similar situation, the answer is to set the bounds of the view as follows so it moves a little under the UINavigationBar

```
self.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0, 10.0, 320.0, 480.0);
```

Hence, this displays the background through the UINavigationBar